# Suggestion to implement custom bean initialization/creation logic in Spring

Tags: java, spring

In my Java/spring project there are lots of beans configured in an xml like,

```
<beans>..
  <bean id="beanOne" class=...>
      <property name="x" value="1"/>
      <property name="y" value="something"/>
      <property name="z" value="something else"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

"beanOne"'s properties(x,y,z) values keep changing for different needs/machines. I can create different xml files having different values, one for each need/machine. But I want to write some custom bean creation logic so that I can define different properties in a single properties (or) json file and the custom class takes care of creating the beans with appropriate values from that single properties (or) json file for all needs/machines.

So how to can I do that in spring? - Extend AbstractFactoryBean, implement FactoryBean, implement BeanFactory, or something else? I just need the logic/skeleton of how to do that using spring.

Comment: That is what property files in conjunction with `<context:property-placeholder />` are designed for. Why would you need to reinvent your own?

Comment: For some reason I should implement the logic, and not use the property-placeholder.

Comment: Is it good to use "BeanPostProcessors" to set up bean properties?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to do the same,

1. create the object for your required bean.
2. Set the required properties for that object, you can fetch it from anywhere you want.
3. Register that object in beanFactory as a bean.

Reference : https://wordpress.com/post/anilagrawal038.wordpress.com/3